# Anaconda installation on Ubuntu 22.04 fails-Directory already exists: -u option

Tags: software-installation, anaconda

I am trying to install anaconda on 22.04. I got the following messages:

```
Anaconda3 will now be installed into this location:
/home/zulfikar/anaconda3

  - Press ENTER to confirm the location
  - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
  - Or specify a different location below

[/home/zulfikar/anaconda3] >>>
ERROR: File or directory already exists: '/home/zulfikar/anaconda3'
If you want to update an existing installation, use the -u option.
zulfikar@lc2530:~$ bash -u  anaconda.sh
anaconda.sh: line 10: LD_LIBRARY_PATH: unbound variable
zulfikar@lc2530:~$ anaconda-navigator
anaconda-navigator: command not found
zulfikar@lc2530:~$ bash -u anaconda.sh
anaconda.sh: line 10: LD_LIBRARY_PATH: unbound variable
zulfikar@lc2530:~$
```

Somebody please guide me how to use -u option.

Zulfi.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular installer, but you are passing the `-u` option to *bash* - to pass it to the installer, you'd use `bash anaconda.sh -u` (or just `./anaconda.sh -u` if you have made the installer executable)