# Anaconda execution on Ubuntu 22.04: Green circle appears and then disappears but can't see application running

Tags: execute-command, anaconda

I am trying to install anaconda on Ubuntu 22.04. Initially I got 'directory already exists':
[Directory Exists](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1484107/anaconda-installation-on-ubuntu-22-04-fails-directory-already-exists-u-option)
which suggested:
$ ./anaconda.sh -u

bash: ./anaconda.sh: Permission denied

zulfikar@lc2530:~$

I also got help from:
[Other forum](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/1655dgd/comment/jycarpm/?context=3)

I modified their solution and completed the installation

Then I tried:

```
zulfikar@lc2530:~$ anaconda-navigator
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
2023-08-30 06:46:21,675 - ERROR download_api._get_url:417
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zulfikar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/main_window.py", line 499, in setup
    self.post_setup(conda_data=conda_data)
  File "/home/zulfikar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/main_window.py", line 536, in post_setup
    self.tab_home.setup(conda_data)
  File "/home/zulfikar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/tabs/home.py", line 169, in setup
    self.set_applications(applications, packages)
  File "/home/zulfikar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/tabs/home.py", line 204, in set_applications
    apps = self.api.process_apps(applications, prefix=self.current_prefix)
  File "/home/zulfikar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/anaconda_api.py", line 903, in process_apps
    versions=[vsdata.get('productVersion')],
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I saw a green circle and after 5 to 10 minutes I came again but there was no green circle. I ran it again and again same delay but application did not load.

However, anaconda is working on my 18.04.

Somebody, please guide me.

Zulfi.